# Typescript strip all type information and just output plain JS - ignore all imports and other errors

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript file and want to just strip all the typescript info out of it and output the Javascript.

I don't want to see errors (imports that don't exist, types that are not defined, etc...) I just want to remove the type information.

How do I do that?

Comment: Your question is `generate javascript code from typescript even with error`?

Comment: I have a typescript file and I want typescript to output the valid javascript while ignoring any typescript errors.

Comment: I don't think the `tsc` supports this. Also, you do not seem to be the only one who's wanted this. See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29651

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio you can uncheck the `do not emit outputs if any errors are reported`.

Go to the `properties` (Press alt + shift) and in `Typescript Build` tab and uncheck the `do not emit outputs if any errors are reported`.

And finally build your project or save typescript file to generate javascript file.

[image]